# Suitable anchors for installing Shelf on 1 1/4 " drywall backed with seemingly impenetrable material

Tags: drywall, drywall-anchor, shelf

I am hanging up some speakers for my stereo on the wall, on opposite sides of the living room.

One is already up, and was able to easily anchor into a stud.

The other side has no studs, so I will have to anchor it into drywall. The speaker is hefty (55 lbs), so I planned to use Toggle Bolts. However, I soon realized I could only drill 1 1/4 inch into the drywall before I hit some sort of impenetrable material. At first I thought there was a gap between the drywall and this material that the bold could expand into, but after drilling a bigger hole found there is little to no gap at all.

Are there any drywall anchors that would be appropriate to hold 55 lbs with nothing to grab onto except 1 1/4" of drywall?

I will have six of them, which I am hoping will distribute the weight enough to make it feasible - but I have also heard that the weight limit does not increase if you add more anchors (although that makes little sense to me from a physics perspective).

Anyway, Looking for suggestions on how, if at all, I can anchor a 55lbs speaker into 1 1/4" drywall with nothing else I can grip into.

[Here are some photos to help describe the context](https://imgur.com/a/aRkQkkn)

Comment: There is no 1-1/4" drywall that I know of. Which means probably 2 layers of drywall (quite possible) on top of *something*. Need to figure out what that *something* is. Most common is some form of brick, concrete block or concrete slab. But could be metal or??? Cut out a large chunk - say 6" x 6" and then you'll be able to figure out what is really there.

Comment: could it be a water or gas pipe

Comment: Could be the drywall is set on furring strips that are anchored to a CMU (or similarly solid) wall.  OP, can you drill out your hole a bit and see what's behind the drywall?

Comment: I should mention this is a rental, so I don't want to do any more excavation of the drywall that absolutely necessary.

Comment: Also I don't care as much what the material is, if I can't go into it easily, I can't, and I need to find some way to hold up the speaker, ideally in that exact spot. Ideally there are strong reliable expansion anchors? Drill into cabinet instead of the wall? Place it on a stand on top the counter?